# 60 sec delay between BIOS and GRUB screen

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, bios

I have a dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows 7 setup. Both are on the same SSD. When I installed Mint 13 a while ago it put Grub on there and I got this strange delay: after the BIOS finishes loading, a blinking cursor (underscore) comes up on the screen and it takes 60 seconds before it changes into that purplish one and I can choose an OS. (The 10 sec delay there is fine.)

I just put reformatted Mint's partition and put Ubuntu 13.04 on there and I believe I replaced the Grub on that SSD in the process. That delay is still there. Any ideas?

I also ran boot-repair (with default settings) and that didn't have any effect.

Comment: Do you have any external hard disks attached. I found these gave me a huge lag of 30 to 35 seconds.

Comment: I have two internal HDDs as well. If I hit F8 and choose the SSD directly it still takes this long, so I'm thinking that it's not that the BIOS is scanning those drives or something. I'll try removing them and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I also had a bunch of bad sectors on one of my internal drives which probably didn't help the situation. I swapped it for a better one.

Comment: I actually had three HDDs, and when I unplugged one of them the problem went away. There you have it.

Comment: Peter, scan that hard disk for errors if you can, I have a feeling that this was the cause of my problems.

Comment: There are 13,147 bad sectors on the disk. I guess it's on the way out--my other drives had 267, 2, and 0. ntfsfix doesn't do much (it's ntfs formatted). I got GSmartControl and now I have more data than I know what to do with. I'm going to back up everything (naturally), run a longer test (because I can) and probably buy a new drive (been several years, prices dropped, etc). Interestingly GSmartControl and Ubuntu's disk utility have different ideas of what counts as "pre-failure". (But really, isn't existence itself just the act of being in a perpetual state of pre-failure?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that your problem could be hardware related rather than due to any software issues.

If you have any external hard disks attached, try disconnecting them one at a time to see if it is one of these that is causing the problem. *I had a similar problem which was giving me a huge lag of 30 to 35 seconds.*

Next, if you check your hard drives for bad sectors as this could also be part or all of your problem _I also had a bunch of bad sectors on one of my internal drives this probably didn't help the situation. I swapped it for a better one.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as much as I hate to answer my own question, it was one of the hard drives. Unplugged it and the problem went away. SimplySimon deserves credit for the answer.

Comment: Yeah, if there's some way for you to get whatever points this site gives out let me know. You can create your own answer and I'll select it or whatever it takes.